# Trying to take hr tags near each other

Tags: html, css, styles

I have two hr tags and i am trying to take them near each other but they go under each other what should i do for this 
here are my codes 
html

`<hr style="margin-right: 2%;width:70%;border-width:2px;border-color:black;border-radius:4px;">`

there are two of these hr tags this is the second one

`<hr style="margin-right: 2%;width: 2%;border-width:2px;border-color:black;border-radius:4px;">`

now what should i do to these lines go near each other like this

---

Comment: for what use 2? It looks like one so use use one `hr`...Can you explain

Comment: Could you explain, what you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: don't pay attention to like this i wrote correct but site did that and maked it to 2

Comment: i am tryin to take tow tags in one line with a little margin

Comment: tow tags you mean `hr` tag or `div`???

Comment: have your tried display:inline-block, and why you are going with hr, you can use 3 divs in order to achieve the result you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give border bottom for both div's. Try to avoid hr tag. If you need that hr tag then use bootstrap column method. it will be essay

Answer (score 1):

Just make them `display: inline-block`

```
hr {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/alexmoronto/pen/aaboNj

Answer (score 0):

**Use `display:flex` and instead `hr` use `div` and in style use `border` and `margin`**

```css
.wrap{
display:flex
}
.line{
border-bottom:1px solid black;
width:50%;
margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

**Or use `display:inline-block;` to `hr` and set `width` and `margin`**

```css
hr{
display:inline-block;
margin:5px;
width:45%;
}
```

```html
<hr/>
<hr/>
```

Comment: that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the width for `big` and `small` lines in their class respectively.

```css
.line-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
}

.line {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.big {
  width: 85%;
  float: left;
}

.small {
  width: 10%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="line-container">
  <span class="line big"></span>
  <span class="line small"></span>
</div>
```